# Bash script not working in bash file but does pasted onto the command line

Tags: bash

I'm not sure if this because of an update to bash or an update to rsync but a script that worked fine for quite a while now gives me an error when I try to run it.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me what's changed, or at least why it's not working if not what changed.

This is the error I get when running from the script file:

```
--- Errors ---
unknown option -- -
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
       [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
       [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
       [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
       [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
       [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
       [user@]hostname [command]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
--------------
```

This is the line that the script creates and if I paste it it works but it doesn't work in the file that creates the line:

`rsync -e 'ssh' --rsync-path='sudo rsync' -lrtz --delete --human-readable -go --usermap=deamon:wwwrun,xxx:yyy --groupmap=_www:www,staff:users --info=progress2 --exclude-from=exclude.list "xxx@tau:'/Users/xxx/Jobs/'" "/home/xxx/Jobs/PHP/Drupal/zzz/"`

Here is the code:
File: ./sync-common.sh

```
function mySync() {

    local OPTIND
    local domain=''
    local dst=''
    local src=''
    local ssh_user=''
    local usermap=''
    local groupmap=''
    while getopts D:d:g:s:U:u: opt
    do
      case $opt in
        D) domain="$OPTARG"    ;; # ssh Domain
        d) dst="$OPTARG"       ;; # Destination
        g) groupmap="$OPTARG"  ;; # Group mapping
        s) src="$OPTARG"       ;; # Source
        U) ssh_user="$OPTARG"  ;; # ssh User
        u) usermap="$OPTARG"   ;; # User mapping
      esac
    done

    local cpu_nice_level=10
    local io_nice_class=3

    local exclude_list="--exclude-from=exclude.list"

    if [ "$ssh_user" == "root" ]; then
      local remote_opts="-e 'ssh'"
    else
      local remote_opts="-e 'ssh' --rsync-path='sudo rsync'"
    fi

    local tweaks='--delete --human-readable' # removed --acl for apple.
    local opts="$remote_opts -lrtz $tweaks"
    opts="$opts -go --usermap=$usermap --groupmap=$groupmap"

    if [ -z "$domain" ] || [ "$domain" = '127.0.0.1' ] || [ "$domain" = 'localhost' ]; then
      domain='localhost'
    else
      src="$ssh_user@$domain:'$src'"
    fi

    case $VERBALIZE in
      2) opts="$opts --info=progress2" ;;
      3) opts="$opts -i" ;;
      4) opts="$opts --progress" ;;
      5) opts="$opts -v --info=progress2" ;;
      6) opts="$opts -v -i" ;;
      7) opts="$opts -v --progress" ;;
    esac

    echo
    echo "Src: $src, Dst: $dst"

    echo "rsync $opts $exclude_list \"$src\" \"$dst\""
    local IFS=''  # To prevent shell word splitting which will cause this command to fail
    nice -n $cpu_nice_level \
        rsync $opts $exclude_list "$src" "$dst" 2>error.log

    if [ -s "error.log" ]; then
      echo
      echo '--- Errors ---'
      cat error.log
      echo '--------------'
      echo
    fi
}

if [ "$(whoami)" != 'root' ]; then
    echo 'Run as root user.'
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$DIR" ]; then
  DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
fi

VERBALIZE=2
```

File: ./sync-from-work-computer.sh

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR
. ./sync-common.sh

# Local
base='/home/xxx'
b1="$base/Jobs/PHP/Drupal/yyy/"

# Remote
b2="/Users/yyy/Jobs/"

mySync -D 'tau' -U 'zzz' -s "$b2" -d "$b1" -u 'deamon:wwwrun,xxx:yyy' -g '_www:www,staff:users'
```

Comment: Use bash arrays and properly qoute your arguments. `opts+=("argument1" "argument2");` `rsync "${opts[@]}"`

Comment: the command line is not parsed twice some characters like quotes are not part of arguments. command echoed and parsed command are not the same maybe it would be more useful to change `echo "rsync $opts $exclude_list \"$src\" \"$dst\""` by `printf "<%s>\n" rsync "$opts" "$exclude_list" "$src" "$dst"` to understand how arguments are parsed. Note that command can be parse again with `eval` but it's not good practice as it will lead to safety problems. using arrays is the good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kamil Cuk. Using arrays managed to get consistent behavior between direct command line input and the script in a bash file.